# I'm trying to store the names of Spark Scala columns in an array. Am getting a weird output. [Ljava.lang.String;@197d5a87

Tags: scala, apache-spark

this is my code:

```
val df = spark.read
    .format("csv")
    .option("sep",",")
    .option("inferSchema","true")
    .option("header","true")
    .load(dbPath+"data" +".csv")

val cols = df.columns

println(cols)
```

which outputs:

```
[Ljava.lang.String;@197d5a87
```

How do I just show the column names? Why is it printing this?

Answer (score 4):

You are printing the array object, not the string values within the array. If you would like to print the individual column names on each line you could do something like this:

```scala
cols.foreach { println }
```

Another nice way to print the columns (well actually, the schema of the data frame) is by calling the `.printSchema` method:

```scala
df.printSchema
```

Answer (score 0):

`df.columns` gives an `Array`, which has no meaningful `toString` implementation:

```
public String toString() {
    return this.getClass().getName() + "@" + Integer.toHexString(this.hashCode());
}
```

You can use e.g. `toList` or `toVector` which has a nicer String-representation.

Alternatively, use `mkString()` on your Array